# PHP Count Arrays from MySQL counts Incorrectly

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, count

I am having trouble correctly counting elements within the array that I pulled from my database. Please see my code below:

```
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) 
{
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully!"; 

//NEW QUERY TO OUR DATABASE
$query = $conn -> query("Select distinct Race from Races");
while($race[] = $query->fetch_object());

//Check how many elements are within our query
$racecount = count($race);
echo "<br>" . $racecount . "<br><br>";
$racecount = count($race,COUNT_RECURSIVE);
echo "<br>" . $racecount . "<br><br>";

var_dump($race);

echo "<br><br><br>";
```

Using both type count() in both ways yields the same result of "4". However, please see the result from my var_dump.

```
array(4) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#3 (1) { ["Race"]=> string(5) "Human" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#4 (1) { ["Race"]=> string(7) "Vampire" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#5 (1) { ["Race"]=> string(5) "Demon" } [3]=> NULL }
```

Var_dump shows that it is an array with 4 elements within it. So count was correct, it's just not giving me the number that I'm looking for.

Thus, I have three questions.

1) How do I count my elements correctly?

2) Could someone explain to me why this reads as 4 elements?

3) Is my array not multi-dimensional? (since both counts yield the same result of 4)

Best Regards and Thanks in advance,

Josh

Comment: it's not a multidimensional array, as the array contains objects, not other arrays.

Comment: what result would you have expected? 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is actually pretty straight forward. When inserting data into your array using `while($race[] = $query->fetch_object())` you always insert the final `$query->fetch_object()` which is gonna be equal to `null`. That is when you exit your `while` loop. Thus, your array's last item will always be `null`, just like in your own `var_dump`.

One way to fix this would simply to subtract 1 from your result. Another way would be to implement inserting like this:

```
$race = [];
while($row = $query->fetch_object()) {
    array_push($race , $row);
}
```

---

The best way to count however would be by simply executing an SQL COUNT command:

```
$query = $conn->query("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Race) FROM Races");
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I wasn't aware of the differences between fetch_object(), fetch_assoc(), and fetch_array(). I also didn't notice that it was counting the "NULL" at the end. It looks like I'm going to have to do some more reading so I can learn which I should be using when getting data from my database. In the meantime I'll be using array_push. Again, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
`while($race[] = $query->fetch_object());`
```

`$query->fetch_object()` returns a `null` to indicate that there are no more entries in the dataset, but you're still assigning that `null` value to your `$race` array as a last entry, and only then allowing the `while` to terminate its loop.... that's why you have 4 entries in the array rather than 3.

Your array is **not** multidimensional, because the entities stored in the `$races` array are **objects**, not arrays; it would only be multi-dimensional if it was an array of arrays

Answer (score -1):

Your php count is returning the amount of fields on your result object, not the amount of rows.

Try this for your SQL query:

```
$query = $conn->query("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Race) FROM Races");
```

Should you wish to use the same query as you have now, try:

```
$raceCount = $query->num_rows;
```